# Linux socket C application - How to ensure messages from one server to many other servers are successful all or failed all?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm implementing my system with many servers communicating with others via Linux UDP socket.

Let's say the scenario: From server A, I want to send a command (UDP message) to server B, C and D. Sever B, C, D will do the command and the result can be success or failed.

**The problem is that how to ensure the command has to be successful all or failed all. For example, if the result on B and C are success but the result on D are failed, I want that the command are failed all so that B and C do not apply the command.**

So could you suggest me how i should implement. Is there any mechanism that i can apply to handle it? I really appreciate any recommendation from field experts

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you want a version of a [two-phase commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol).

Comment: It seems to be what i'm looking for. Thank you